# метод GET в php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Как методом `GET` получить информацию с базы данных по определенному `id`? то есть при клике на условно клиента номер 11 высветить всю инфу из базы данных по клиенту с номером 11. `(localhost/phpmyadmin)` . В строке `url` примерно что такое должно быть 
`clinet.php?id=1`.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой пример, не основе драйвера `PDO` Который я советую использовать в дальнейшем.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
if($id >= 0) {
    $response = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?');
    $respons->execute([$id]);

    $arrInfo =  $response->fetchAll();

    foreach($arrInfo as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['name'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так можно. Адаптировать под свои нужды. А впредь такие вопросы ищутся в поиске...

```
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if ($id > 0) {
        /** @var Mysqli $mysqli */
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
        if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id")) {
            var_dump($result->fetch_assoc());
        }
        $result->close();
    }
```

Comment: На каждый `GET` подключение к `msyql`?

Comment: Это же пример, я не буду писать готовый скрипт, чтобы просто скопировали) Подключение одно, далее при заходе на страницу client.php?id=11 покажет одного пользователя, так и задумано

Answer (score 0):

Если не усложнять, а просто показать принцип, то можно так.

```
$id=(int)$_GET['id'];

$query->(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id);
```

Comment: Так нельзя. Давайте не будем показывать даже простой принцип написания sql инъекций

Comment: Вопрос не про sql инъекцию. Человек не понимает элементарного принцыпа, а вы его грузите кучей дополнительного кода. Я когда начинал учиться, от таких примеров сидел в недоумении и хотел просто ответ на свой вопрос, а до плейсхолдеров и прочей защиты дошел тогда, когда готов был.

Comment: В общем, я починил